# SMS to 2 iPhones

Tags: iphone

Why do SMS messages addressed to me also go to my wife. I also get messages addressed to her. We both use iPhones and have an Apple Mac which also connects to iCloud.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm getting your question right: we're talking about SMS/MMS (Green bubble background) or about iMessages (Blue bubble background) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are both using the same Apple ID then it is most likely ['Text Message Forwarding', a feature of Continuity in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204681).

To disable this, go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive and turn un-tick any other numbers that aren't yours.

Also, go to Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding and ensure it is turned off for any devices you don't want your messages showing up on.

Alternatively, look into setting up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201060) so that you and your wife can both have separate Apple IDs.